# How can I code a function to show/hide QMI indicator on the settings ? PINESCRIPT

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-editor

`Experts, I wanted to add a function I can hide/unhide this indicator. so far I tried using

```
showzigzaglen(true, "QMI", "inline=01")
plot(showzigzaglen ? zigzaglen : na)
```

it's not hiding the indicator from the settings or turning it off, I'm trying to accomplish adding this to my indicator strategy that will let me separate it from the other when I don't want to see it.`

```
//@version=5
indicator("Quasimodo Pattern", "QML", overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000, max_labels_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

//INPUTS
zigzag_len = input.int(13, "ZigZag Length", inline = "01")
var float[] high_points_arr = array.new_float(5)
var int[] high_index_arr = array.new_int(5)
var float[] low_points_arr = array.new_float(5)
var int[] low_index_arr = array.new_int(5)

//Indicators
to_up = high >= ta.highest(zigzag_len)
to_down = low <= ta.lowest(zigzag_len)
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], 1)
trend := trend == 1 and to_down ? -1 : trend == -1 and to_up ? 1 : trend
last_trend_up_since = ta.barssince(to_up[1])
low_val = ta.lowest(nz(last_trend_up_since > 0 ? last_trend_up_since : 1, 1))
low_index = bar_index - ta.barssince(low_val == low)
last_trend_down_since = ta.barssince(to_down[1])
high_val = ta.highest(nz(last_trend_down_since > 0 ? last_trend_down_since : 1, 1))
high_index = bar_index - ta.barssince(high_val == high)

//Conditions
if ta.change(trend) != 0
if trend == 1
array.push(low_points_arr, low_val)
array.push(low_index_arr, low_index)
if trend == -1
array.push(high_points_arr, high_val)
array.push(high_index_arr, high_index)
f_get_high(ind) =>
[array.get(high_points_arr, array.size(high_points_arr) - 1 - ind), array.get(high_index_arr, array.size(high_index_arr) - 1 - ind)]
f_get_low(ind) =>
[array.get(low_points_arr, array.size(low_points_arr) - 1 - ind), array.get(low_index_arr, array.size(low_index_arr) - 1 - ind)]
[h0, h0i] = f_get_high(0)
[l0, l0i] = f_get_low(0)
[h1, h1i] = f_get_high(1)
[l1, l1i] = f_get_low(1)
[h2, h2i] = f_get_high(2)
[l2, l2i] = f_get_low(2)
~~~
bu_cond = trend == -1 and h2 > h1 and l1 > l0 and h0 > h1 and close > l1
be_cond = trend == 1 and l2 < l1 and h1 < h0 and l0 < l1 and close < h1

if bu_cond and not bu_cond[1]
 line.new(h2i, h2, l1i, l1, color=color.green, width=2)
 line.new(l1i, l1, h1i, h1, color=color.green, width=2)
 line.new(h1i, h1, l0i, l0, color=color.green, width=2)
 line.new(l0i, l0, h0i, h0, color=color.green, width=2)
 line.new(l1i, l1, bar_index, l1, color=color.green, width=2)
 label.new(bar_index, l1, "QM!", style=label.style_label_up, textcolor=color.white, color=color.green,   size=size.tiny)
alert("Bullish QM!", alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if be_cond and not be_cond[1]
line.new(l2i, l2, h1i, h1, color=color.red, width=2)
 line.new(h1i, h1, l1i, l1, color=color.red, width=2)
 line.new(l1i, l1, h0i, h0, color=color.red, width=2)
 line.new(h0i, h0, l0i, l0, color=color.red, width=2)
 line.new(h1i, h1, bar_index, h1, color=color.red, width=2)
 label.new(bar_index, h1, "QM!", style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.white, color=color.red,    size=size.tiny)
 alert("Bearish QM!", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the `input` correctly:

```
showzigzaglen = input.bool(true, "QMI", inline="01")
```

Since this indicator is not using `plot` but rather it uses `line`, you'll need to use it before calling `line`:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Quasimodo Pattern", "QML", overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000, max_labels_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

//INPUTS
zigzag_len = input.int(13, "ZigZag Length", inline = "01")
showzigzaglen = input.bool(true, "QMI", inline="01")

var float[] high_points_arr = array.new_float(5)
var int[] high_index_arr = array.new_int(5)
var float[] low_points_arr = array.new_float(5)
var int[] low_index_arr = array.new_int(5)

//Indicators
to_up = high >= ta.highest(zigzag_len)
to_down = low <= ta.lowest(zigzag_len)
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], 1)
trend := trend == 1 and to_down ? -1 : trend == -1 and to_up ? 1 : trend
last_trend_up_since = ta.barssince(to_up[1])
low_val = ta.lowest(nz(last_trend_up_since > 0 ? last_trend_up_since : 1, 1))
low_index = bar_index - ta.barssince(low_val == low)
last_trend_down_since = ta.barssince(to_down[1])
high_val = ta.highest(nz(last_trend_down_since > 0 ? last_trend_down_since : 1, 1))
high_index = bar_index - ta.barssince(high_val == high)

//Conditions
if ta.change(trend) != 0
    if trend == 1
        array.push(low_points_arr, low_val)
        array.push(low_index_arr, low_index)
    if trend == -1
        array.push(high_points_arr, high_val)
        array.push(high_index_arr, high_index)

f_get_high(ind) =>
    [array.get(high_points_arr, array.size(high_points_arr) - 1 - ind), array.get(high_index_arr, array.size(high_index_arr) - 1 - ind)]
f_get_low(ind) =>
    [array.get(low_points_arr, array.size(low_points_arr) - 1 - ind), array.get(low_index_arr, array.size(low_index_arr) - 1 - ind)]


[h0, h0i] = f_get_high(0)
[l0, l0i] = f_get_low(0)
[h1, h1i] = f_get_high(1)
[l1, l1i] = f_get_low(1)
[h2, h2i] = f_get_high(2)
[l2, l2i] = f_get_low(2)

bu_cond = trend == -1 and h2 > h1 and l1 > l0 and h0 > h1 and close > l1
be_cond = trend == 1 and l2 < l1 and h1 < h0 and l0 < l1 and close < h1

if bu_cond and not bu_cond[1] and showzigzaglen
    line.new(h2i, h2, l1i, l1, color=color.green, width=2)
    line.new(l1i, l1, h1i, h1, color=color.green, width=2)
    line.new(h1i, h1, l0i, l0, color=color.green, width=2)
    line.new(l0i, l0, h0i, h0, color=color.green, width=2)
    line.new(l1i, l1, bar_index, l1, color=color.green, width=2)
    label.new(bar_index, l1, "QM!", style=label.style_label_up, textcolor=color.white, color=color.green,   size=size.tiny)
    alert("Bullish QM!", alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if be_cond and not be_cond[1] and showzigzaglen
    line.new(l2i, l2, h1i, h1, color=color.red, width=2)
    line.new(h1i, h1, l1i, l1, color=color.red, width=2)
    line.new(l1i, l1, h0i, h0, color=color.red, width=2)
    line.new(h0i, h0, l0i, l0, color=color.red, width=2)
    line.new(h1i, h1, bar_index, h1, color=color.red, width=2)
    label.new(bar_index, h1, "QM!", style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.white, color=color.red,    size=size.tiny)
    alert("Bearish QM!", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```